# Creating Alias in LINQ with SelectMany

Tags: c#, linq

I have a viewmodel like this:

```
public class FileInfo
{
    private string _fileNo;
    private string _fileName;

    public string FileNo
    {
        get
        {
            return _fileNo;
        }
        set
        {
            _fileNo = value;
        }
    }

    public string FileName
    {
        get
        {
            return _fileName;
        }
        set
        {
            _fileName = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a List DataList with data and FileNo may have duplications.

I can use below LINQ to get all data from DataList with condition like this:

```
List<FileInfo> ViewList = DataList.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.FileName))
               .GroupBy(y => y.FileNo)
               .SelectMany(z => z).ToList();
```

How of I get Alias name in the SelectMany and also .ToList() for above query, it should look something like this:

```
List<FileInfo> ViewList = DataList.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.FileName))
                   .GroupBy(y => y.FileNo)
                   .SelectMany(new {...NewFileName = "Row " + FileNo + FileName, NewFileNo = "No " + FileNo}).ToList();
```

Any pointers would be highly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You want to project the result to a new type ? You should more read about c# clases, check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes

Comment: You really should have looked up the docs for `SelectMany` and anonymous types as you would have learnt more doing that than any answer here will give you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as below -

```
var ViewList =
    DataList
        .Where(x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.FileName))
        .GroupBy(y => new { FileNo = y.FileNo })
        .SelectMany(x =>
            x.Select(y => new
                {
                    NewFileName = "Row " + y.FileNo + y.FileName,
                    NewFileNo = "No " + y.FileNo
                }))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: How can I cast it to List<FileInfo>  directly by this query too? not a anonymous List<T>. Thank you.

Comment: make y => new FileInfo and change NewFileName and NewFileNo to FileName and FileNo respectively.